# изменить позицию Collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Есть `picker`, и снизу есть `Collection view`. После Тапа на любой из элементов пикера - нужно изменить позицию в `Collection view`. 
Я предполагаю что это нужно реализовать тут. Но как реализовать пока не нашел.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    titleLabel.text = journalItem[row].date
    myPickerView.isHidden = true
    // по текущему row нужно изменить изменить позицию Collectionview cell               
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так заработало

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    titleLabel.text = journalItem[row].date
    myPickerView.isHidden = true

//        let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: myCollectionView.contentOffset, size: myCollectionView.bounds.size)
//        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX - 100, y: visibleRect.midY)
//        myCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)

    let indexPathPicker = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
    myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPathPicker, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.right, animated: true)

}
```

Но к сожалению ячейка не по центру встает, а с правого краю, есть ли у кого какие предложения? Скроллинг проходит по горизонтали.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ту же функцию, только с аргументом `centeredVertically`
`myCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPathPicker, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredVertically, animated: true)`

Comment: да, я уже сделал, забыл просто отписаться.